# Change default library path in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

While running my project on eclipse, I got this error:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
```

By googling it, it seems that some class definitions are missing, and here, in my case, I need to download the library from [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi). I added it in my project, but the problem is that, the classes definitions needed are in org.apache.commons.lang3. So I'm asking if there is a way to change the default path to org.apache.commons.lang3. Or is there any other way to fix this?

By the way, here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JSONArray jsonArray = JSONArray.fromObject( "['json','is','easy']" );  
}
}
```

Comment: did you do import `org.apache.commons.lang3.*;` ? Did you add the external jar to your build path?

Comment: Importing `org.apache.commons.lang3.*;` didn't change anything. Yes, I added the jar library to build path.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found it. I just need to download the `commons-lang-2.6-bin.zip` instead of the `commons-lang3-3.1-bin.zip`.